# php MySQL multiple words search

Tags: php, mysql

This is the `music`. table It contains `artists` and `titles`. Artists are separated by commas if more than one artist sing a song. I want to set up a search function so users can search for one artist, both artists, no artists and title etc.

Table `music`:

```
|      artist     |    title   |
|------------------------------|
|eminem,lil wayne |   no love  |
|kida             |   o'najr   |
```

User may search like this:

```
eminem no love
lil wayne no love
no love eminem
no love lil wayne
```

Also user can or can not type special chars like `'`
if user search:

```
kida onajr
kida o najr
kida o'najr
```

the result should be the same.

This is my code up to now:

```
$search_value = "...";
$query = "select * from `music` where `title` like '%$search_value%' or `artist` like '%$search_value%'";
```

But if I search `lil wayne no love` no results are shown.

Comment: How does this differ from [your other question?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26002251/)

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759580/how-to-implement-a-keyword-search-in-mysql

Comment: It has nothing to do with multiple words search. @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [MATCH AGAINST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/fulltext-search.html) for those kinda search.

Comment: Like this? 
select * from `music` match(`title`, `artist`) against ('%$search_value%')

This is giving me an error.

Comment: You've got to break your search values into single ones. That's not your LIKE pattern.

Comment: @rexhn You have to add `FULLTEXT(title,artist)` in your table, you have to remake it or do an ALTER TABLE. Read the documentation.